# Statistical methods to profile clusters

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, clustering, unsupervised-learning

I am working on a clustering exercise and now I need to generate business insights by profiling the clusters(provide a brief description of each cluster. Eg : Cluster 1 mostly consists of high salaried people with high spending and Cluster 2  consists of low salaried people with low spending power). There are some standards ways of profiling clusters like :

1. Calculating the mean of each variable in different clusters and tag clusters accordingly.
2. Get important features from Random Forest classifier by treating cluster labels as response variable. tag clusters based on the important features extracted.

However, are there any other statistical techniques like t-test, chi-squared test, etc to identify the variable that best describes or represents a cluster?

Mainly we want to extract the most important feature that describes the cluster and tag that cluster accordingly.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are there any other statistical techniques like t-test, chi-squared test, etc to identify the variable that best describes or represents a cluster?